# "accept dreams as being real" or "accept dreams as real"

Tags: grammar, meaning, phrase-meaning, idiomatic-language, adverbial-phrases

**"During sleep, you accept unrealistic dream events as being real."**

**"The elderly sometimes recall dreamed events as being real."**

When I think about **"...accept/recall something as being real"** in the above sentences, the **"being"** sounds redundant and may even be omitted, but then when I repeat the sentence to myself (omitting being), something does not sound right, but I can't explain it in technical terms why it sounds not right or why we can or cannot omit **"being"** in such structures.

So I really wonder why would it be - if it would be- wrong to say **"...accept/recall something as adjective"**, instead of **"accept/recall something as being adjective?"**

Would it really be all right, if we omitted **"being"** in the above structures?

Answer (score 3):

In this case, sure, you could omit "being" and not change the meaning. It's possible to imagine some other sentence, though, in which it could create some confusion between accepting the adjective and accepting the noun. Maybe, say, "You must accept my plan as reasonable." Here it's a little unclear whether you're just accepting *that* the plan is reasonable, or accepting the plan itself. (And in this case, it would be better to just turn the adjective into a noun anyway: "You must accept the reasonableness of my plan."